# How to use Exodus Directory with Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, xodus

I have this simple Lucene code:

```java
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("C:/temp/Lucene"));
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
```

How can I use *Exodus Directory* in Java instead of the `FSDirectory`?

Answer (score 2):

`ExodusDirectory` should be used atop of `ContextualEnvironment`:

```java
ContextualEnvironment env = Environments.newContextualInstance(..);
ExodusDirectory dir = new ExodusDirectory(env, VfsConfig.DEFAULT, StoreConfig.WITHOUT_DUPLICATES_WITH_PREFIXING, new ExodusDirectoryConfig());
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
writer = env.computeInTransaction(txn -> {
            try {
                return new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Configuration parameters of ExodusDirectory can tuned, but `StoreConfig.WITHOUT_DUPLICATES_WITH_PREFIXING` is preferable for using.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the lucene index operations do not need to be done in a transaction? Or that it needs another transaction at a later time for read and/or write?

Comment: Method `computeInTransaction` does create a transaction and executes an action in it. Any write operation requires a R/W transaction. Searching in the index can be performed in a read-only transaction.